# Replacing <br/> that comes from sql reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is what I do when I update row in db

```
TextBox_Thing.Text.Replace("\n", "<br/>")
```

It works fine when I retrieve things from database, cause I can see all those break points. Problem comes when I want to edit that inserted text because it automatically adds the `<br/>` to my TextBox and If I would click on update while having `<br/>` in that multiline textbox, error is appearing.

This is how I retrieve my text from database to the same textbox

```
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
    TextBox_Thing.Text = reader["user_thing"].ToString();

}
```

How to do that ._ .? Can I somehow replace it back to `\n` while retrieving it to textbox from reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text  = reader["user_thing"].ToString(); 
text = text.Replace("<br/>", "\n")
TextBox_Thing.Text = text;
```

You can use Replace again to just reverse your previous text replacement. The Replace method can be used on any string no matter where it comes from and what it is used for.

However, you should rethink your general approach.

When you just replace the line breaks and then at some point want to output the text as html, what happens to the other parts of the text that use characters which are part of the HTML Syntax?

For example, if the user inputs the text

> `A<B means that B>A`

If you output that as HTML, you will only see

> AA

Always use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` on text entered by users or coming from other sources that could contain html syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing that wrong way. That is why I couldn't manage to make it work reader["user_thing"].ToString().Replace("<br/>", "\n"):  That is what I tried xD @NineBerry